# Bootstrap - Columns within a Column Overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a bootstrap container with the following columns (and columns nested within another column):

```
col-md-2
col-md-8
    col-md-4
    col-md-4
    col-md-4
col-md-2
```

The columns inside the larger column end up overlapping when the screen is resized to a smaller width. I added a margin around those embedded columns, but they still horizontally overlap within each other. I'd like to keep the padding and maybe even expand it.

How can I keep the content in the columns from overlapping when the screen expands and shrinks? Here is the code for the column:
https://jsbin.com/gowehatijo/edit?html,css

Here is the full view (try slowly expanding and shrinking):
https://output.jsbin.com/gowehatijo

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>


<br>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="background-color: #bfbfbf">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>


    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height: 130px;">
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
            <div>
              <button class="btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>    
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
             <div>
              <button class="btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
             <div>
              <button class="btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>          
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  margin: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 127, 255, .3);
  border: 2px black solid;

}

.btn:hover {

  background: rgba(0, 127, 255, 1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making your buttons too wide with all that padding. If you want block level buttons, use the `btn-block` class for sizing instead:

```
.btn, .btn-lg.btn-block.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 127, 255, .3);
  border: 2px black solid;
}

<button class="btn-lg btn-block btn">test test test test</button>
```

Full example:

```css
.btn, .btn-lg.btn-block.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 127, 255, .3);
  border: 2px black solid;
}

.btn:hover {

  background: rgba(0, 127, 255, 1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="background-color: #bfbfbf">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>


    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="min-height: 130px;">
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
            <div>
              <button class="btn-lg btn-block btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>    
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
             <div>
              <button class="btn-lg btn-block btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-4" align=center>
             <div>
              <button class="btn-lg btn-block btn">test test test test</button>
            </div>          
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the layout itself, it is the button width.

To fix this try to set a width for this buttons, remove the previous one or just set

`max-width:100%` on the button rule.

Comment: this works but the text is not stay aligned in the center of the box